# How do you perform an intersection of two named regex character classes in Java?

Tags: java, regex, intersection

I know how to find the intersection of two constant sets from this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) to the Java tutorials.

Example:

```
 [0-9&&[345]]
```

Will produce a character class containing all of the characters which intersect the set of single digit integers ('[0-9]') and a subset of that set containing the integers 3, 4, and 5 ('[345]').

This works fine for most needs, but it requires that both sets be known at compile-time. Let's say I'm writing a lexical analyzer for mathematical expressions and want to find the intersection between the set of unary operators and binary operators. Currently, the only operator that exists in both sets is '-'. As a binary operator '-' represents subtraction but as a unary operator it also represents negation. I anticipate that other operators may be pressed into dual-usage in the future, and want to develop a solution that not only works for the present case, but also the future case without changing the code. To do that, I need to be able to determine at run-time which operators exist in both sets.

Let's say I have two character classes defined as follows:

```
public static final String UNARYOPS = "[!~-]";
public static final String BINARYOPS = "[|&%^*/+-]";
```

How would I find the intersection between these two named character sets using the regex engine in Java so that I can identify which operators need to be checked for ambiguity between binary and unary?

Comment: You can't.  Another limitation of regexes is that they are not capable of making a (good) cup of tea.  :-)

Comment: You could use brute force over all (64K) Unicode chars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in regex operator for those two single expressions. You have to hard-code it yourself.

Side note: Your regular expressions contain a "-" in a character class which have a special meaning and must be escaped:

```
public static final String UNARYOPS = "[!~\\-]";
public static final String BINARYOPS = "[|&%^*/+\\-]";
```

And now either do it on the string level:

```
String regex = UNARYOPS.substring(0, UNARYOPS.length() - 1) + "&&" + BINARYOPS + "]";
```

Or you put all characters of the character classes into a set, each. Then intersect these sets.